# Unity Android Google Pixel 2 (Arm) Crash

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When i Update a app to google play, then the Pre-launch test report details shows some errors, which are crash in Google Pixel 2 (Arm)

```
Exception java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.3.14f1 (d0d1bb862f9d)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:13/TE1A.220922.033/10836537:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-10-18 05:32:03-0700
pid: 10384, tid: 10394, name: ReferenceQueueD  >>> com.footman.oilpaintingcolorbynumber <<<
uid: 10181
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  b4000073b5cd1570  x1  00000076276df54c  x2  00000076276df54c  x3  000000732ac6f6b8
    x4  0000000000000046  x5  0000007395c81440  x6  0000000000000001  x7  0000577200006548
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000002dde  x10 0000000000000060  x11 0000000000000018
    x12 000000000000d4b5  x13 0000675c0000485a  x14 000000000000ea42  x15 000005d0c25fb059
    x16 00000073873fb438  x17 000000763235b040  x18 0000007328214000  x19 b400007455ca8bd0
    x20 b400007455ca8bd0  x21 b400007505caafc0  x22 b400007455cbadf0  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 0000000000000001  x25 00000000153a4618  x26 0000000070f810c8  x27 0000000070d25e70
    x28 0000000000000055  x29 000000732ac6f6d0
    sp  000000732ac6f6d0  lr  00000073873f21bc  pc  000000763235b05c
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000020305c  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicui18n.so (icu_70::RegexMatcher::~RegexMatcher()+28) (BuildId: cdd644fa9dfbce19ec4df433d2b5ba0b)
      #01 pc 00000000000081b8  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicu_jni.so (MatcherState::~MatcherState()+60) (BuildId: 8aa0304b65c89ffe38fe194ef4f2ccd3)
      #02 pc 000000000000fdfc  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicu_jni.so (BuildId: 8aa0304b65c89ffe38fe194ef4f2ccd3)
      #03 pc 0000000000011e08  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (BuildId: 50be351c037c9ef19c64a12189d8d997f90b5f9f)
    at libicui18n.icu_70::RegexMatcher::~RegexMatcher()(~RegexMatcher:28)
    at libicu_jni.MatcherState::~MatcherState()(~MatcherState:60)
  at libicu_jni
  at boot-core-libart
```

so I have to found the reason. Because my mac cpu is intel, so i can't create avd of pixel2 arm.
I have to use firebase Testlab.

I create a new empty project and export new abb (i use Unity 2020 and 2022 to test), upload to testlab then found expect pixel2 arm others pass the test,

[image]
[image]

then i use my old version which had passed the google Pre-launch test then upload to testlab, the result is same, crash again.

so the empty project can't pass the pixel2 arm.

And the google pre-launch test will use the same devices to test next aab, and i don't know it will impact to the Official version.

any suggestions？

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed by unchecking "***Optimized Frame Pacing***" in Unity (2022.3.1f1).
in **PlayerSettings->Player->Resolution and Presentation->Optimized Frame Pacing**
[image: Optimized Frame Pacing]

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
I had the exact same problem.

**Unity version:** 2022.3.11f1

I got the same error:

```
   *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2022.3.11f1 (d00248457e15)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:13/TE1A.220922.033/10836537:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-10-19 05:11:02.819728478-0700
pid: 9805, tid: 9937, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> com.Zystam.Klootn <<<
uid: 10181
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000026d1  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000725d413420
    x4  0000000000808080  x5  0000000000808080  x6  0000000000808080  x7  8080808080808080
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  000000762762ea00  x10 0000000000000001  x11 000000762766cde4
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 000000000000e258  x15 0000000000000030
    x16 00000076276d1d58  x17 00000076276aec70  x18 0000007256aec000  x19 000000000000264d
    x20 00000000000026d1  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 000000725d414000
    x24 00000000000ca438  x25 b400007485db3930  x26 00000072d13b0100  x27 000000724000018c
    x28 000000725d414000  x29 000000725d4134a0
    lr  000000762765e968  sp  000000725d413400  pc  000000762765e994  pst 0000000000001000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000051994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #01 pc 0000000000041814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::map(void*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, scudo::MapPlatformData*)) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #02 pc 0000000000041ec0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportError(char const*)) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #03 pc 0000000000042220  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::stringifyAction(scudo::AllocatorAction)) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #04 pc 0000000000043a20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so 

...
```

It didn't not matter whether I built on my PC or Unity build automation.

**Firebase Testlab (different unity versions):**

Test succeeded on new **Unity 2021.3.31f1** (empty project).
[Firebase Testlab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWk5J.png)

Test succeeded on **Unity 2023.1.17f1** (empty project)
[Firebase Testlab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeP3o.png)

**Problem Solved**

I upgraded my project to **Unity 2023.1.17f1**, and uploaded my app to the store without a problem.

After updating to Unity 2023 the problem is solved.

**Other possible solutions:**

If you still want to use Unity 2022.3, I suggest **upgrading your JDK**. The Unity 2023.1 version comes with a newer version of the JDK.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated to Unity2023.1.17, and pass the test.

Comment: But other old project has not upgraded, it will take a lot of time to upgrade.

Comment: Maybe you can upgrade your older project’s SDK/ JDK and have it work. Not sure. Let me know if it worked